# convert Rect to vector<Point>

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV and need to convert a `cv::Rect` to a `std::vector<cv::Point>` of all the points in the `Rect`.

I wonder if there is a method that can do this?
If not, how can I populate the `std::vector` with my points?

I tried adding the points in the constructor, but it fails:

```
cv::Rect rect
std::vector<cv::Point> _contour(rect.tl(),rect.br());
```

the error I'm getting is

> no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with
>   _Ty=cv::Point, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list

I tried to add the points using the `insert` function, but this fails too:

```
cv::Rect rect
std::vector<cv::Point> _contour;
_contour.insert(rect.tl());
```

the error I'm getting is:

> no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert
>   [with _Ty=cv::Point, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the
>   argument list

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code failing using the `insert` function, along with the error message.

Comment: @BoBTFish thanks for your comment, i add the code and the error to the question

Comment: The [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) function in `std::vector` is used when inserting a *range* of elements. To insert a single element, use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) (or [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)).

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the return type of rect.tl() is a point, you can use an initialization list to construct the vector:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> _contour { rect.tl(), rect.br() };
```

And as BoBTFish mentioned, you should use push_back instead of insert :

```
std::vector<cv::Point> _contour;
_contour.push_back(rect.tl());
```

An other way: you know the size of your vector and you change value:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> _contour(2);
_contour[0] = rect.tl();
_contour[1] = rect.br();
```